# How to limit Smallint maximum value 32k to a fixed number?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I've a game server and character stats(Strength, Dexterity,..) are saved as Smallint and the maximum value is 32767 due Smallint limits. SQL Server 2008.

Players constantly edit this table by adding stats on the game. Right now they can add up to 32767 but I don't want that.

Is there a way I can limit how many stats can be added to this table? For example limit it to 3500 max and if a player gets over that it doesn't let them.

Comment: Please define “doesn’t let them in”. Do you mean the database throws an exception if an attempt is made to save a value greater than some limit? Is that limit fixed for all rows, or variable depending on the row? Does the limit ever change?

Comment: Please provide an example in the form of data and how you're defining your "limit"

Comment: You'd normally enforce such a limit in your application... afterall if SQL Server throws an error its still your application which has to do something with that.

Comment: Databases hold data, they shouldn't be ued to enforce application behaviour.  Make your application (Game Server) validate the data before even submitting it for storage in the database.

Comment: Seems like a check constraint will accomplish your goal at the column level.